# What tool do you use for debugging Javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I've notices I'm not capable to debug correctly js. I'm only using alert() as a spread sentences technique but I need something better. So... which tool do you use?

Comment: have found this video tutorial http://www.viddler.com/explore/ringmaster/videos/5/

Comment: On Linux, your best bet is Firebug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Firefox [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) it's the best, has a lot of useful features, the [Console API](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) is great, you can log, make assertions, profiling, timing and much more.

For IE, the [Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(VS.85).aspx) of IE 8 is better than nothing, for earlier versions of IE, try the [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en).

For Chrome and Safari, check the WebKit inspector and debugging [tools](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html).

Answer (score 7):

In Firefox, Firebug and its [console](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) which provides a panel for debugging along with an object for programmatically evaluating inside of a script, eg

```
console.log('test')
```

Safari and the family of Webkit enhanced browsers have built-in [inspectors/consoles](http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html).

Opera has [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/).

There are several plugins for Internet Explorer, such as DebugBar and IE8 has a pretty neat built-in [Developer Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If you're on Linux you can even install spidermonkey-bin, which is the interpreter used by Firefox and invoke it with `js` in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and IE8 have surprisingly good debugging consoles.

If you use Firefox, you'll need to install Firebug to compete.

Comment: Chrome and Safari share the Webkit debugging. They are getting better very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

For cross-browser logging you could use [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org).

Answer (score 1):

Firebug is very good. However, if you are on Windows you should check out the Developer Tools in IE 8. The integrated debugger allows for breakpoints and uses a lot of great elements probably taken from Visual Studio concepts.  You have an interactive console, etc. You can get to it using F12.

Comment: I work on Linux. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) is also good in a pinch

Answer (score 0):

Firebug's a must. I've recently also started to use IE8's inner debugging tool and it's pretty nice as well.

Answer (score 0):

To track down performance issues:

- Of course there is [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with [Yahoo's yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) plugin
- Internet Explorer has [dynaTrace Ajax](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/) (John Resig [blogged about it lately](http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/)).
- Google Chrome now has the [Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/) extension.

Comment: Is it a debugger, or an optimizer?

Comment: well yeah, it's more a profiler - not a step debugger
but it gives you traces which can be used for debugging purposes